# How should we choose the dimensions of the encoding layer in auto-encoders?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders, hyperparameter-optimization, variational-autoencoder, hyper-parameters

How should we choose the dimensions of the encoding layer in auto-encoders?

Answer (score 3):

The number of dimensions is a hyperparameter of your model, and you should do a hyperparameter search, like with any other parameters. There's also a tradeoff between dimension and training speed, so it should be small enough to be trainable in a reasonable time.